# In Pycharm How to load code to interactive debugger?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to be able to load and run several line of code into interactive debugger, to make sure the code works fine. By doing so I don't need to rerun from the beginning of the code, which takes much longer time. I tried two methods but neither work.  Coming from R and Matlab, I do prefer this feature.
Anyone can suggest?

Method 1:
According to [interactive shell debugging with pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329601/interactive-shell-debugging-with-pycharm), one can load the code typed in pycharm editor to interactive debugger by

```
1> set a debugging point
2> highlight the code you want to load to Python console
3> alt+shift+E
```

When I follow these steps: I set the debug point, debug the code to trigger the debug point, and select the code press alt+shift+e.Instead of loading the code to the debug console, it loaded to the python console by default. I don't have access to variables and packages that I want to debug under the python console context.

I have to minimize the python console, then run it again. Sometimes it runs in debugger console. Below answer suggests to "select the console you want to target". What is the step? you click the debugger? then select the code and press atl+shift+e? I tried, it does not work.

EDIT: found  the official doc but not very helpful:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/loading-code-from-editor-into-console.html

[image]

Method2:
Type and experiment the code directly in the interactive debugger console. However, there is no easy way to bring the code (multiple lines) back to the editor. The console history is sorted automatically from the newest to oldest. When copied from console history, you have your last line of desired code as the first line in the editor.
See below threads, I have the same issue.
[How to invert console history order in pycharm for copy pasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650709/how-to-invert-console-history-order-in-pycharm-for-copy-pasting)

Comment: Just use the previously mentioned Evaluate Expression (Alt+F8) window in Code Fragment Mode and copy/paste whatever code you like there.

Comment: It isn't answer to the question, but can be helpful. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK3mK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HK3mK.png)

Answer (score 9):

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will invoke the command "Execute Selection in Console". If there is no open console already, PyCharm will open a regular (non-debug) Python console.

To execute the selection in a *debugger* console, you first need to have the debugger running. You need to run a script using the debugger and pause it with a breakpoint, then the command will behave as expected.

If you have more than one open console, e.g. one regular and one debugger, you must activate the target console before performing the keyboard command.

Comment: from my screenshot you can see that i'm already in debug mode. But when pressing alt+shift+E, it still runs in the regular python console. I have to minimize the regular python console, and press alt+shit+E again to run it in debug console.

Comment: When I tested this, `Alt+Shift+E` would send the selection to the currently active console. So when you have several consoles open, you first need to select the one you want to target.

Comment: Still struggling. I set the debug point, debug the code, and select the code, it loaded to the python console instead of debugger console by default.I have to minimize the python console, then run it again and sometimes it runs in debugger console. What did you fo for "select the one you want to target?" you click the debugger? the select the code and press atl+shift+e?

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. However, I can't get it to work myself now. Whenever the debugger is active and I select some code in an editor and try to execute it, the Python Console area flickers but doesn't update. I've updated my PyCharm version since last time, so maybe it has stopped working.

Comment: @ Dag Høidahl did you find the alternative way to debug?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? You can paste the code into the console, or execute the code by selecting it and run Evaluate Expression (`alt+F8`). Does that help you?

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I might be off on this a little bit but from my use of R I have felt the frustration the comes from running code by selection. For instance if you select a block of code that initializes some variables with the debugging mode and later delete them in your source things may get a little messy later if the source you had selectively run is altered. Also running code piece wise sometimes buggers the order, but the urge to run code from the top every time is certainly well fought by the wait time required to accomplish certain tasks.

So the question is, when you restart pycharm does the does the python console remember the things that you ran in it last time you had pycharm open? No it doesn't but when you run your program the plot ovbiously works because plt is defined on line 2. If you just run line 6 without line 2 you have problems.

Also it looks like you set a breakpoint on line six which is another matter entirely...

Answer (score 3):

1. First make sure you have properly closed (not just hidden) the console by clicking the close console button on the left, which is a red X (see [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/interactive-console.html)).
2. Now (re-)open the console and click the "attach debugger" icon, which the green bug icon second from the bottom on the left (just above the green plus). It should become pushed in and grey.
3. Now if you import your modules and run functions in them within, any breakpoints set in those functions should be hit like normal and you can single-step through them, just like when you're debugging a script. You can do this by typing directly in the console or by selecting code and choosing "execute in console" as described in another answer. It seems like the stack trace doesn't work though (in my quick test). For example, if you have function "fn()" in file "foo.py" in directory "dir", try this:

   `import dir.foo
   dir.foo.fn()`
4. If you change your code after you import it, the Python console will still be using the old code. (If you then stop at breakpoints, this can get very confusing.) You can force an update to the new code by calling the `reload` function as show below. Alternatively, go back to step 1 (which is a good idea if things start to break confusingly).

   `from importlib import reload  # This line only needed on Python 3
   reload(dir.foo)`

Comment: I tried, but the behavior is not always consistent. When I place the debug point inside a function, the variable cannot be accessed through the python console. However, if the debug point is at the main, some of the variables are accessible, but not dataframes.

Comment: Is there a chance you have attached the debugger after importing the module?

Comment: would you edit your answer give more details? Do you load the code into python console? or debugger? do you run under debug mode? I want to make sure your answer helps more people

Comment: I added a bit more detail. Hopefully it's a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Alhough it is not a pycharm's feature, I would strongly suggest trying [jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org/). It is very useful for prototyping.

If, you want to do it the pycharm way, as Dag Høidahl pointed out, one option is to execute block of code in console with `Alt+Shift+E`.

However, to fully leverage the awesome Pycharm's debugger, you should write an [unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383/what-is-unit-testing) calling particular piece of code which you want to test (or debug). This way you can add breakpoints properly debug, or automatically ensure expected behavior in the future. 
Nevertheless, writing unit tests has many other advantages you will appreciate.

Comment: Is there a way to do this by simply clicking on the filename? Usually what's needed is to run the entire script in the console without typing the entire path.

Comment: try right clicking the file in pycharm and select "Run ..." option

Comment: It runs it in a new instance, not in the console.